# Python yield JSON docs from a stream

Tags: python, json, ravendb

I have a REST API ([RavenDB's Query Streaming](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/unbounded-results?version=2.5)) that returns a *lot* of data in JSON format. It's too much to load into memory and parse in one go:

The issue is that rather than 'one document per line', which would make it very easy, it returns a single string with our documents in a field called "Results", as follows:

```
{"Results":[
  {"Name":"Hello World"}
]}
```

What I really want to do is use python's requests library to stream the response like so:

```
r = requests.get('.../streams/query/Raven/DocumentsByEntityName?query=', stream=True)
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512, decode_unicode=False):
    print chunk
```

But I want to yield individual JSON documents, so as not to have to parse the entire response. What would be the most efficient way to yield one JSON document at a time?

Answer (score 1):

`json.load()` has an optional `object_pairs_hook` argument which you may be able to use.  The idea is to capture each inner `dict` as it goes along, returning from your callback function an empty dict (or maybe `None`) so as to avoid building up the gigantic data structure in memory.

Keep in mind that this is not a performance optimization: in my testing (using `import simplejson as json`), I found that while I could save memory, using the hooks to inspect each element made the parsing actually several times slower.  Still, if you are out of memory, it's better than nothing.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how that might work to yield only the inner dictionaries from {"Results":[{}]} ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am going about things at the moment. What I am doing is matching the braces ({}) so that I can output *just* the inner JSON documents, one per line (see: [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)).

The buys me the ability to stream the output to a text file which I can decode per-line later on without having to decode the whole item in memory.

Any suggestions or optimizations would be most welcome!

```
def yield_stream(url1 = '/streams/query/Raven/DocumentsByEntityName?query=', query1=''):
    r = requests.get(conf.db + url1 + query1, auth=conf.db_auth, stream=True)
    i = 0
    is_doc = False
    is_str = False
    doc1 = []
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024, decode_unicode=True):
        for char in chunk:
            if is_doc:
                doc1.append(char)

            if doc1[-2:-1] != ['\\'] and doc1[-1:] == ['"']:
                is_str = not is_str

            if char == '{' and not is_str: 
                i += 1
                if i == 2:
                    doc1.append(char)
                    is_doc = True

            if char == '}' and not is_str: 
                i -= 1
                if i == 1:
                    yield ''.join(doc1)
                    doc1 = []
                    is_doc = False
```